# jinja2 base template overrides the rest of the page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have this base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div>
    Microblog:
    <a href="/index">Home</a>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</div>
```

And I want to extend it

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
```

but when loading the page, I see only the base part of the page, not the title block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write empty block code in base template and overwrite it in extended template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div>
    <div>
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    Microblog:
    <a href="/index">Home</a>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</div>
```

Extended template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
```